# Генерация заданого количества массивов из исходного с одинаковой суммой элементов

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, генераторы

Введение. 
Разрабатываю генератор тестов. Если база вопрос, со сложностью от 1-3. Необходимо сгенерировать заданное количество вариантов с заданным количеством вопросов (во всех одинаковое количество), и важно, что сложность варианта была одинакова, то есть сумма по полю сложность.

Суть в чем. 
Есть исходный массив, состоящий из объектов с полями:  `id` - идентификатор, `complex` - числовая переменная, значения в диапазоне от 1 до 3 включительно.

Задача: 
Сгенерировать заданное количество массивов с заданным количеством элементов (не больше длины исходного) из исходного, где каждый элемент в сгенерированных массивах встречается в нем один раз и сумма полей `complex`  во всех массивах приблизительно одинаковая.

Comment: *Задача: Сгенерировать заданное количество массивов* Достаточно написать генерацию одного такого массива. И обеспечить не-рестарт генератора случайных чисел. А по сути - делаем копию исходника и генерим вариант. Тупо берём случайный элемент в вариант, выбрасывая его из копии исходника, на основании текущей суммы и заданной выбрасываем из копии элементы, которые не позволят получить заданную сумму (слишком малы или велики), и повторяем, пока не наберём необходимое количество.

Comment: По окончании сравниваем полученные варианты, дубликаты выбрасываем и генерим недостающее (или сразу генери м больше, выбрасываем дубликаты, выбираем нужное количество вариантов).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть, просто определиться - сколько вопросов уровня 1, сколько - 2 и 3, и потом выбирать вопросы случайным образом из соответствующей категории?

Плюс в том, что все тесты будут еще и "равнособранными", не будет так, что один - только из средних вопросов, а другой - из простых и сложных... Еще хуже - один из большого количества простых, второй - из небольшого сложных - такой тест ничего не скажет об уровне первого отвечающего.

Ну, а как обеспечить выборку без повторений - тут уже обсуждалось не раз.

Comment: Да, проблема и оказалась в том их уравновесить по сложности. Генерацию без учёта уровня сложности сделать просто. У меня есть идея разбить на разные подмассивы по уровням сложности, но как мутно вырисовывается алгоритм в голове.

Comment: Но такое разбиение - это уже задача не из области программирования :( Тут уж вы оценивайте сложность вопросов...